# Missing detection in some frames while using deepstream yolo detection on two videos

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, gstreamer, nvidia, nvidia-deepstream

I am using deepstream pipeline (custom deepstream-test3) for detection. I used my custom yolov4 model, converted using https://github.com/marcoslucianops/DeepStream-Yolo this repo, and got the “.so” file.

When I run it on one video there are no missing detections. But while running on two videos, there are missing detections in a few frames. While running on two same videos also see the same issue and also miss on a different frame, there will not be detected in both videos at the same time. It seems the detection just switches from one frame to another in case of multi-streaming and skipping the frame to detect.

The python deepstream file https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps/blob/master/apps/deepstream-test3/deepstream_test_3.py

The config file https://github.com/marcoslucianops/DeepStream-Yolo/blob/master/config_infer_primary.txt

Answer (score 0):

This was happening due to that repo. The owner of the git repo made the changes, and working properly now.